# Windows Phone 7 Client Server communication

Tags: windows-phone-7, client-server

I want to make a client server communication application on WP7..

I saw classes such as WebRequest, HttpWebrequest, and WCF terminologies in establishing a client server communication.

I need to build 2 simple applications now.

One should be an unsafe way of making a request, so that fiddler can capture the data in clear text and expose the data that was moving. And another should be solution for the same, using a secure medium, which goes encrypted or fiddler cant capture it.

Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is rather generic, I can only recommend using HttpWebRequest unless you want/need WCF functionality.

- A web request using a HTTP:// URL is not secured in any way and can
  be captured on the network.
- A web request using a HTTPS:// URL is encrypted over the network and
  can not (easily) be intercepted.

I say easily since there have been recent problems with certificate authorities, but you can for most intents and purposes consider a HTTPS request "automatically" being secure.